# Dynamic transition component VueJS 2

Tags: components, transition, vuejs2

I would like to be able to switch between transition A and B dynamically

### Parent component

```
<child></child>
```

### Child component

#### Transition A

```
<transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
</transition>

.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to /* .fade-leave-active in <2.1.8 */ {
  opacity: 0
}
```

#### Transition B (using animate.css library)

```
 <transition
    name="custom-classes-transition"
    enter-active-class="animated tada"
    leave-active-class="animated bounceOutRight"
  >
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
```

Comment: I can see this working [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/mimani/9z4zj5za/), Can you reproduce your case?

Comment: The thing is instead of just changing the name of the transition I would like to use custom class for one but no for the other. First transition would be a transtition with name fade. The second transition would use custom class, like SlideInUp from animate.css

Comment: Somehting like that : https://fiddle.jshell.net/j9h3Lmr5/ (it is not working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the dynamic transition with properly assigning the `enterClass` and `leaveClass`. Here is the working demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/j9h3Lmr5/1/

**JS**:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',
  data: {
    show: true,
    transitionType: "fade",
    enterClass: "fade-enter",
    leaveClass: "fade-enter-active"
  },
  methods: {
    changeTransition() {
      if (this.transitionType === "fade") {
        this.transitionType = "custom-classes-transition"
        this.enterClass = "animated slideInUp"
        this.leaveClass = "animated slideOutDown"
      } else {
        this.transitionType = "fade"
          this.enterClass = "fade-enter"
          this.leaveClass = "fade-enter-active"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was confused about ! Thanks a lot